# Why "def put(x: Int): Unit" works, but "def put(x: Int): ()" doesn't?

Tags: scala

Why does the following work where `Unit` is the return type

```
def put(x: Int): Unit
```

while putting `()` as the return type

```
def put(x: Int): ()
```

gives `=> expected` error. What is the difference between the two signatures?

Comment: `()` is not a type. Why did you expect it to work? I mean... Yes, there are enough other languages where `()` would be a valid type, but in Scala it's not a type. `Unit` is the type. Don't know what else can be done here.

Comment: Perhaps you have seen `def put(x: Int) = ()`, which is equivalent to `def put(x: Int): Unit = ()`. This could be used to define a function that does nothing, maybe cos the author means to come back to it later (though `???` is better for that)

Comment: Thanks! I think you answered, so () is the unique thing with Unit type. I got it. I found this example in a book. @AndreyTyukin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `()` is a value of the type `Unit`, similar to how `7` is a value of the type `Int`, so writing

```
def put(x: Int): ()
```

is a bit like writing

```
def f(x: Int): 7
```

where we have erroneously put a *value* in the position where return *type* is expected.

Comment: Funny thing, if [**Literal Singleton Types**](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/singleton-types.html) gets included in Scala 3, this will compile :D

Comment: Probably not the exact syntax with `()` in return type as `Unit` is already singleton.

Comment: If and when this is implanted, I would expect the *Literal Singleton Type* of `()` to be identical to `().type` to be identical to `Unit`.